# Jquery Counter from 0% to 100% with step function

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have 2 divs, the blue one is set to 365px width (this will actually be the page height so i cant pre determine it)

then the grey one i need to count from 0 - 100%

at the moment it counts from 365 to 0

http://jsfiddle.net/Bill/BNVyq/

Comment: That jsfiddle link is invalid.

Comment: please share another link your link is broken

Comment: You could also use a `<progress>` tag if you want: http://jsfiddle.net/BNVyq/5/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the `width` of the css `#loading_line` to `0` and the `width` in the `animate` to `100`.

Also see the updated [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/scessor/BNVyq/1/).

=== UPDATE ===

I've updated your [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/scessor/BNVyq/6/).
Change your data calculation to

```
var data = now / onepercent;
```

and move it after the onepercent calculation.

Comment: Yeah its a good idea if i could set the div to 100px width, unfortunately I cant. ive set it to 365 but it could be any number depending on the browser height